# Snowflake Get value from XML column

Tags: sql, xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working in Snowflake

I need a specific value from XML

```
SELECT data_xml,REGEXP_SUBSTR(data_xml,'<pinLessNetworkBin>(.*?)(</pinLessNetworkBin>)',3) as network
FROM  "DW"."DB"."TABLE"
```

My results for now

```
<pinLessNetworkBin>STAR</pinLessNetworkBin>
```

I just need the value inside

Here the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:FundingSource xmlns:ns0="www.url.com/be/example/payments/model/Concepts/FundingSource" Id="12887819260" extId="">
  <id>3939</id>
  <pinLessNetworkBin>STAR</pinLessNetworkBin>
</ns0:FundingSource>
```

How I can get that value?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the contents of an XML object is retrieved via `GET(object, '$')` thus for your regex result `GET(parse_xml(network), '$')`  will get you the content. See [GET](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/xmlget.html#usage-notes)

or you should really retrieve the `pinLessNetworkBin` via [XMLGET](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/xmlget.html):

```
SELECT data_xml,
    XMLGET(parse_xml(data_xml), 'pinLessNetworkBin') as pinLessNetworkBin
FROM  "DW"."DB"."TABLE" 
  parse_xml(data_xml)
```

which will give you the `<pinLessNetworkBin>STAR</pinLessNetworkBin>` thus you want to fetch the contents

```
SELECT data_xml,
    get(XMLGET(parse_xml(data_xml), 'pinLessNetworkBin'), '$') as pinLessNetworkBin
FROM  "DW"."DB"."TABLE" 
  parse_xml(data_xml)
```

should give you 'STAR'

see the [PARSE_XML](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_xml.html)

Comment: Hi Simeon that really works by one question, the result show me "STAR" any idea how to display without ""  and show me just STAR. Regards

Comment: @Webb it depends what you are view it in, but `::TEXT` should cast it to a string from the variant object.